# Is there a size limit for LocalShared Objects created on Mobile apps (iOS/Android) with AIR?

Tags: android, ios, air, shared-objects

For a mobile app project I am caching lot of data for offline use into the app.

So far I've been using Classic SharedObjects, storing every data in a couple of fat xmls (as strings in SharedObjects). The images are saved through the FileSystem Class.

I'm now wondering if it is good practice or if I should write my xmls in Files rather than Shared Objects.

My SharedObject's size is 3.6 Mo.

Thanks :)

Comment: You also can use SQLite to store data, you even can put there your xmls as TEXT, or even BLOB data (after simple string compression).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AIR, it is generally recommended (by developers on here and the Adobe forums as well as the occasional Adobe evangelist) that you avoid using `SharedObject` entirely. It's meant to be used as a way to store files in a browser's temp file directory. With AIR, you are given far more control using the `File` and `FileStream` classes.

As for a size limit, the docs state the max size for a `SharedObject` is 100 kb. That is, as far as I know, a soft limit. It varies based on client, but it should always be around 100 kb. This is one of the main reasons why it is recommended you use the `File` and `FileStream` classes - there is no size limit (beyond the 4GB max file size for a 32 bit system, obviously). You also have full control over the location of the object, the life cycle of it, the security of it, etc.

In short, I highly recommend switching to using the `File` and `FileStream` classes when using AIR and use `SharedObject` *only* when working with a browser-based SWF