# SharedObject good on FlashPlayer but nogo on AIR

Tags: flash, air

The code, below, writes normally when publishing to FlashPlayer. It does not write at all when publishing to AIR (3.9) on Windows 7 or XP. I hope it's just me and not a major prob. with AIR.

```
package source

{
  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  import flash.net.SharedObject;

  public class MAIN extends MovieClip
  {
    var mySO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myThing","/")

  public function MAIN()
  {
    var thing:int = 12;
    mySO.data.sharedthing = thing;
    mySO.flush();
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

When publishing with **AIR**, location of SharedObject file:

Windows 7

```
 C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\<swfname>\Local Store\#SharedObjects
```

Windows XP

```
 C:\Documents and Settings\<UserName>\Application Data
```

with **Flash Player**:

Windows 7

```
 C:\Documents and Settings\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\4YW7LFD8\localhost
```

Windows XP

```
 C:\Documents and Settings\<UserName>\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\2QL2PDA2\localhost\path\to\<swf_name.swf\
```

Comment: For the record,it is generally recommended you **not** use `SharedObject` when using AIR. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966502/is-there-a-size-limit-for-localshared-objects-created-on-mobile-apps-ios-androi/22972653#22972653) from a few days ago regarding it.

Comment: I appreciate this, but it's not quite clear to me WHY SharedObject should not be used with AIR. I thought that the point of S.O. was to allow the stashing of all sorts of very small data, e.g. arrays containing objects or numbers, or small bits of text. It seems to be an efficient way of tucking away binary data. What can go wrong with S.O. under AIR?

Comment: Basically, it lacks sufficient control over your data and it is extremely limited in what you can store (100kb size limit is nothing). The point of SharedObject was to allow for small amounts of Flash data to be safely (for the end user) saved to a directory meant to be temporary. With AIR, you are given actual tools for saving data to disk, not adapting something meant to be used in browser-based Flash